# How to add XML-Annotations automatically

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a huge number of entity-classes and they all need to be annotated with XML-Annotations in order to send them as xml with JAX-RS.

Is there way in eclipse or a third party tool that does this automatically? 
It's really annoying....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack.

Open all classes with Notepad++, and *replace all* `public class` with `@Annotation public class`.

I hope you don't have nested public classes.